# How to deal with double quotes in JavaScript when referencing a C# variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, string

I'm needing to call a JavaScript function that takes in a string variable that could have double quotes in it.  Here's how I pass my variable into the JavaScript function:

```
onclick="copyDescription('<%# Eval("Description") %>');"
```

The problem is the function never fires because it doesn't like the quotes that might be in the 'Description' variable.

'Description', for example, could be:

```
VALVE BALL 1" 2000 RP THRD NACE SS BALON LS-10561
```

If I remove the double quote from the above description, it works great.  I further tested this out by doing the following, and it worked as expected:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var str = 'VALVE BALL 1" 2000 RP THRD NACE SS BALON LS-10561';
        copyDescription(str);
    });
```

I tried doing a .replace('"','\"') and a .replace('"','') via JavaScript, but neither worked.  I can remove the quotes by modifying the C# code that gets the value to remove the double quote, and it works.  Just not through JavaScript.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with which was the answer to my question was to use:

```
onclick="copyDescription('<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Description").ToString()) %>');"
```

Server.HtmlEncode works how I need it to.

Thanks everyone for your help and answers!

Comment: How about trying a `'` in the description

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `"` is terminating the **HTML attribute** and cutting off the JS mid-statement.

Double quotes must be represented as `&quot;` in attribute values delimited by double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) and call function `JavaScriptEncode()` on your string

Comment: I've had a hunt, but I can't find any documentation which explains what `JavaScriptEncode` actually does. It looks, however, like it won't solve this problem and that `HtmlAttributeEncode` is needed instead (which will, presumably, deal with the quote characters to get the result described in my answer).

Comment: @Quentin For the following string: `"This is a \"test\""` running `JavaScriptEncode` will produce: `"'This is a \x22test\x22'"` Open the [dll](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=325) in reflector if you want to se how it works.

Comment: Ah, that will do the job as well then.

Answer (score -4):

Have that Eval call output JSON instead or plaintext. That'll take care of any embedded Javascript metacharacters. I don't know how that'd be done in C#, but in PHP it's simply:

```
 onclick="copyDescription(<?php echo json_encode(...) ?>);"
```

Comment: This really isn't helpful, although I appreciate your effort.